# Сериализация Texture с помощью Newtonsoft.JSON

Tags: c#, json, unity3d, сериализация, текстура

#### Описание

Для начала познакомлю с одним классом написанным мною который ускоряет сохранение:

```cs
public class Archive<Type> {
    public Archive(string path, Type initial) {
        _Path = path;
        if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey(_Path) && initial != null) {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString(_Path, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(initial, Formatting.Indented));
        }
    }
    private string _Path;
    public Type Read() {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey(_Path)) {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Type>(PlayerPrefs.GetString(_Path));
        } else {
            throw new Exception($"Key '{_Path}' is undefined.");
        }
    }
    public void Write(Type value) {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, Formatting.Indented);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString(_Path, json);
    }
    public void Change(Func<Type, Type> action) {
        Write(action(Read()));
    }
}
```

Используется вот так:

```cs
var archiveTextures = new Archive<Texture[]>("Textures", new Texture[] {});
var textures = archiveTextures .Read();
textures[0] = null;
archiveTextures.Write(textures);
```

Либо ещё удобнее

```cs
var archiveTextures = new Archive<Texture[]>("Textures", new Texture[] {});
archiveTextures.Change((textures) => {
    textures[0] = null;
    return textures;
});
```

Суть в том что класс при сохранении преобразует объект в JSON и сохраняет с помощью `PlayerPrefs`. Вот и в этом проблема, что свойство `normalized` в `Texture` является циркулярным и преобразование в JSON выходит с ошибкой.

> JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'normalized' with type 'UnityEngine.Vector2'

Поиски привели мне в [официальный сайт Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/hongyes/loop-reference-handling-in-web-api) где по идеи решают эту проблему игнорируя циркулярные объекты. А при таком решении у меня не удается преобразовать обратно в `Texture` поскольку в объекте отсутствуют свойства.

#### Вопрос

Как правильно сериализовать именно `Texture` в JSON и обратно?

---

#### Дополнение 1

На данный момент проблема решена при помощи нового класса `TextureData`...

```cs
class TextureData {
    public int Width;
    public int Height;
    public byte[] Bytes;
    public TextureFormat Format;
}
```

```cs
Texture anyTexture;

TextureData FromTexture(Texture texture) {
    return new TextureData() {
        Width = texture.width;
        Height = texture.height;
        Format = texture.format;
        Bytes = texture.GetRawTextureData();
    };
}

var archiveTextures = new Archive<TextureData[]>("Textures", new TextureData[] {});
archiveTextures.Change((textures) => {
    textures[0] = FromTexture(anyTexture);
    return textures;
})
```

```cs
Texture ToTexture(TextureData data) {
    var texture = new Texture2D(data.Width, data.Height, data.Format, false);
    texture.LoadRawTextureData(data.Bytes);
    texture.Apply();
    return texture as Texture;
}

Texture anyTexture = ToTexture(archiveTextures.Read()[0]);
```

... который хранит в себе примитивные данные для создания текстуры. Думаю что мое решение не лучшее. Ищу метод получше.

Comment: [Preserving Object References](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/preserveobjectreferences.htm)

Comment: По приведённой вами ссылке есть примеры как игнорирования циклических ссылок, так и их сохранения.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Та же ошибка, что с этой настройкой, что без - `JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'normalized' with type 'UnityEngine.Vector2'`

Answer (score 0):

- нижнее подчеркивание в нейминге приватных полей это хорошо, но по конвенции они еще с маленькой буквы и перед конструктором
- `path` и `key` это разные вещи, а `initial` вообще в лексиконе программиста статус а не целевой объект
- `PlayerPrefs.SetString(key, value)` не сохраняет, сохраняет [PlayerPrefs.Save()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.Save.html)
- после `textures = null` она остается в памяти, как и все `UnityEngine.Object` они удаляются через `Destroy(object)`
- `Texture` это базовый класс для `Texture2D` и `Texture3D`
- У `Texture2D` есть [GetRawTextureData](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetRawTextureData.html) выдающий `byte[]` с которым работать в плане сериализации куда проще
- `JsonConvert`? А [JsonUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html) в `Unity3D` для кого? Хотя сериализовать предпочтительней модели `class` или `struct`, а не массивы, с ними могут возникунть проблемы
- уже по неймингам видно, что код понймет машина, но мало какой человек, а `Change`... балуемся функциональмы программирование... такое себе занятие

Comment: • Перед конструктором пишу, статические члены. • Именование стандартное, просто для собственного понятия. • `PlayerPrefs.SetString(key, value)` пишет в строку - это я знаю. Формулировка описания скорее всего кривое. • `textures = null` это всего лишь пример.  • `Texture` потому что при загрузке с сервера получаю `Texture`, а не `Texture2D` или `Texture3D`.  • На данный момент с помощью `GetRawTextureData` и решена проблема, но для него надо сохранить `width`, `height`, `TextureFormat`.  • `JsonUtility` - кривизна. Не работает нормально с объектами и массивами. И Microsoft перешли на Newtonsoft

Comment: Вот и намечается нормальная модель данных `struct TextureData { public byte[] rawData, public int width, public int height; }` с ней и работай. Много раз читал что `JsonUtility` кривая, еще больше раз пользовался, ни разу не сталкивался c проблемами и никогда не видел упоминаний, что именно с ней не так.

Comment: Попробуйте сохранить что то `Object[,][]` типа

Comment: `Object[,][]`? Как я должен согрешить, что бы у меня вообще оказался подобный монстр? Наскольку безолаберным и не аккуратным нужно быть? Может для тех кто пишет `Func<Type, Type> action` и злоупотреблением лямда выражениями с пренибрежением к именованиям, это в порядке вещей но, не для всех. Любой дурак напишет код понятный машине, но не каждый напишет понятный человеку, не редко этот абстрактный человек это ты сам спустя пару месяцев. Плохому танцору яйца мешают, `JsonUtility` не виноват.

Comment: Если вам захотелось ответить на вопрос, дать совет или чем то помочь - пожалуйста. Написав что `Любой дурак напишет код понятный машине, но не каждый напишет понятный человеку` или же `Плохому танцору яйца мешают` ничем мне не помогает. При таком случае можете просто обходить вопрос стороной.

Comment: Я не прошел мимо и указав как минимум на пару критических косяков в коде. Он у тебя не сохраняет и память тячёт, пример или нет, ты этого явно не знал, и поскольку ты сохраняешь, значит и генерируешь и где-то у тебя это точно есть, а значит пригодится. Могу себе позволить не позволять кидать не обоснованное говно в `JsonUtility` и позволяю. К тому-же было банально интересно прочитать что-же с ним не так, серчить интернеты на эту тему целенаправленно желания не было.

Comment: Я же вижу что ты умеешь писать осмысленный код. Но жаловаться на проблемы порожденные нарушением стандартов, это странно. Видимо из-за того, что ты фулстек с большим акцентом на бекэнде судя по стилю.

Comment: Ну да, угадали. 

Comment: @eccs0103 а чего ответ не принимаете? Не катит?

Comment: @aepot тут разные подсказки для улучшения моего кода. Тут нет ответа на мой вопрос. Если имеете в виду `GetRawTextureData`. Этим методом я и сделал сейчас, ищу метод получше. Сейчас дополню в вопросе.